# Why isn't my notification being triggered?

Tags: swift, push-notification

I am trying to send local push notifications, or now referred to as `UNLocationNotificationTrigger`, but the push notification is not being triggered.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }

        return true
    }
```

View Controller

```
 var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    localLocations()

}

func localLocations() {
    //My current location is equal to the below coordinates, so I am in the radius
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: xx.xxxxx, longitude: -xx.xxxx)
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: 20000, identifier: "Store")
    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = false
    let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = "Grocery Store"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please show your code for _authorizing_ local notifications.

Comment: question updated with code

Answer (score 0):

```
//My current location is equal to the below coordinates, so I am in the radius
// ...
region.notifyOnEntry = true
```

There's your problem. You are already in the region. Therefore you cannot enter it. Therefore the notification does not fire.

Comment: I comment it out, and still nothing

Comment: No, commenting it out won't help. I'm talking about your comment about your current location being "in the radius". So the notification won't fire. You have to actively _cross_ into (for `entry`) or out of (for `exit`) the region in order for the notification to fire. You cannot test while sitting still. It won't fire just because you are "in the radius".

Comment: And here's another point. You do not need to do `startUpdatingLocation` in order to use region notifications. If you _are_ doing `startUpdatingLocation`, you already _know_ where we are, all the time; you don't _need_ to use region notifications. If you _do_ use region notifications, then the whole point is that you should _not_ `startUpdatingLocation`; let the system notify the user as needed.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but say the background is killed in the background how will the app know when I enter the region? All I did was enable background mode, location and notifications and the code above.

Comment: Local notifications have nothing to do with "the app". Region tracking has nothing to do "the app". That is the whole _point_ of these features. They are managed by the system, on your behalf. — You really seem to be trying to use a feature about which you know nothing at all; I strongly recommend getting some knowledge before going any further. There are two excellent WWDC 2016 videos on notifications, plus you should watch the video on use of Core Location.